# NyARToolkit for Android: only loading .md2 models?

Tags: android

I have been using the Android version of NyARToolkit, but I can only load .md2 models.

When I try to load a .3ds model, nothing is displayed.

Has anybody successfully used any model in formats other than .md2?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem .. but the program crashes

but we could at lest use the mqo model "miku01.mqo"  that is attached using the class src\jp\androidgroup\nyartoolkit\ModelRenderer

by deactivating the Comments in NyARToolkitAndroidActivity
and disabling the code of the min3d library

Comment: So you are not using min3d at all? 
Which version are you using?

Comment: ok, I was able to load .MQO models as well, but it is SLOOOOOOOW!! How about yours?